# hyperref fillable forms - breaking the rules

Tags: hyperref, forms

The `hyperref` manual states clearly:

> You must put your fields inside a `Form` environment (only one per file).

However,

1. I can put form fields outside of a `Form` and
2. I can put more than one `Form` in a file

and it seems to work just fine (apart from the general problem even within the rules that the font in the fillable fields seems uncontrollable). See MWE. It is not possible for me to get all my fillable bits in one place. What terrible things will befall me if I breach (1) and (2) above?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

%outside a form
\TextField[name=one, width=3cm, borderwidth=0]{type here:}

%Form 1
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=two, width=3cm, borderwidth=0]{type here:} \\

\TextField[name=three, width=3cm, borderwidth=0]{type here:} \\
\end{Form}

%And another one
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=four, width=3cm, borderwidth=0]{type here:} \\

\TextField[name=five, width=3cm, borderwidth=0]{type here:} \\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You'll unleash the wrath of Heiko :-)

Comment: You'll grow *seven* fingers.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just use a single form?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but small subtle things seem to happen/break.

For example, let's say that you are creating a PDF document, but that you don't provide a `Form` environment at all. If you use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (version 2015.007.20033) to read your generated document, then when you enter your first character the whole GUI freezes approximately one second for some reason (but after that everything seems to work fine). If you instead use Foxit Reader (version 7.1.5.425) you will not get the notification saying "This document contains interactive form fields." that the program usually displays.

So it seems best to follow the manual, as other PDF readers might break in other ways.