# Problem with multiple sets of radio buttons in PDF generated from hyperref

Tags: hyperref, forms

<sup>I know very little about `Form`s with `hyperref`, but I have a suspicion that this might be related to [the fact that you're supposed to only have one `Form` in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131801/hyperref-fillable-forms-breaking-the-rules).</sup>

I would essentially like to create a PDF document that functions as a multiple choice test. That is, I'm hoping to produce a list of questions with each question being followed by a radio button form.

With the following MWE, however, there is a problem with the radio buttons. When viewed with Adobe Reader, you are able to select just one of the radio buttons, but as soon as you select a radio button for the next question, the selection for the preceding question disappears. That is to say, you can *only* select one radio button in the *entire* document.

When viewed with Preview and Skim, it is impossible to select just *one* radio button. Rather, choosing one radio button leads to effectively choosing all of the radio buttons in the same 'column' as the radio button that was selected.

Both of these behaviors persist in these viewers even when you put the `\begin{Form}...\end{Form}` inside of the `\DTLforeach` loop (leading to multiple forms in the document, rather than the one).

<sup>I have not tested any other viewers.</sup>

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{stuff.csv}
stuff,things
Question 1, consectetuer adipiscing elit
Question 2, ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat
Question 3, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper
Question 4,  dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{stuff}{stuff.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\DTLforeach{stuff}{\STUFF=stuff,\THINGS=things}{%
\STUFF\par\THINGS\par
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{A} \hfill \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{B} \hfill \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{C}
\par\bigskip\hrulefill\par\bigskip
}%

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a unique `name` for each multiple choice question. Below I've added `\theDTLrowi` (based on the highest-level row counter of [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) - similar to your question counter) to `myGroupOfRadiobuttons`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{stuff.csv}
stuff,things
Question 1, consectetuer adipiscing elit
Question 2, ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat
Question 3, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper
Question 4,  dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{stuff}{stuff.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\DTLforeach{stuff}{\STUFF=stuff,\THINGS=things}{%
  \STUFF\par\THINGS\par
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name={myGroupOfRadiobuttons\theDTLrowi}]{}{A} \hfill 
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name={myGroupOfRadiobuttons\theDTLrowi}]{}{B} \hfill 
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name={myGroupOfRadiobuttons\theDTLrowi}]{}{C}
  \par\bigskip\hrulefill\par\bigskip
}%

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```